# What machinery is used in Hatcher Thm 2.26?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is related to Hatcher Thm 2.26's proof.

If non empty open subsets $U\subset R^n, V\subset R^m$ are homeomorphic, then $m=n$.

Pf. $x\in U$, then $H_k(U,U-\{x\})=H_k(R^n,R^n-\{0\})$ which is $Z$ if $k=n$ and $0$ otherwise. Similarly $H_k(V,V-\{x\})=H_k(R^m,R^m-\{0\})$ which is $Z$ if $k=m$ and $0$ otherwise. Since $V\cong U$, one induces homology isomorphism which fixes $m=n$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ How did the book conclude for every open $U\subset R^n$, then $H_k(U,U-\{x\})=H_k(R^n,R^n-\{0\})$? I did not find this statement obvious. My reasoning is the following. Since $U$ is open, fix an open ball $B$ in $U$ and its image $B'$ contains a ball. WLOG, the statement specializes to open ball question and we can scale or translate the image in $R^m$ s.t. $B'$ contains unit ball centered at $0$ with the center $B$ at $0$ being sent to $0$. Denote map $f:B\to B'$. Then $f:B-\{0\}\to B'-\{0\}$ is homeomorphism. Now apply deformation retraction to $B'-\{0\}$ conclude $m=n$.

Comment: You mean "$U$ is a ball without loss of generality"?. An open set can be anything really, and you're taking a specific one that you know to be a deformation retract. Or did I misinterpret it?

Comment: @mathworker21 but is the image of that embedding an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: @mathworker21: an embedding of $\Bbb{R}^n$ into $\Bbb{R}^m$ will only map open sets to open sets if $n = m$ (e.g., the $x$-axis is not an open subset of the plane),

Comment: derpedy derp derp

Comment: @PauloMourão It should be obvious the statement is not something global about $U$ but local about $U$. Hence it suffices to restrict $U$ to an open ball contained in $U$ and prove $n=m$. However, you will not know what the image look like and you know it contains a ball by homeomorphism. The deformation retract is only applied to the image after appropriate scaling and centering.

Comment: @user45765 Ah you mean, you can restrict to an open ball because of the original statement you want to prove, sure, yes, I agree. I was just thinking about the result on isomorphism of homology groups, and there your assumption would become weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the excision axiom from the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for a homology theory. It states that if $(X,A)$ is a pair and $U \subset X$ is a subset such that the closure of $U$ is contained in the interior of $A$, then the inclusion from $(X \setminus U, A \setminus U)$ into $(X,A)$ induces an isomorphism on the homology groups.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Excision Theorem 2.20 where $X=\mathbb R^n$, $A = \mathbb R^n - 0$, and $Z = \mathbb R^n-U$.